# What is the name for such construct `[System.iterator]() : Iterator;` inside an interface

Tags: typescript

This article shows the following TS definition:

```
 interface Iterable {
     [Symbol.iterator]() : Iterator;
 }
```

I can't seem to find anything like that [on this TS docs page](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/interfaces.html). Indexable types doesn't seem to fit. So what is this structure?

My question is not about iterators, it's about this particular structure `[Symbol.iterator](): Iterator<string>;`, as in general form `[type]():type`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

These are called iterators and it is actually `Symbol.iterator`, not `System.iterator`. The structure means that the implementing class must be iterable (i.e. `for..of` can be used) and the iterable must expose a mandatory `next` method:

```
interface IterableTest {
    [Symbol.iterator](): Iterator<string>;
}

class MyClass implements IterableTest {
    private count: number = 0;
    public [Symbol.iterator](): Iterator<string> {
        return this;
    }
    public next(): IteratorResult<string> {
        this.count = this.count + 1;
        if (this.count > 5) {
            return {
                done: true,
                value: `Value ${this.count}`
            };
        }
        else {
            return {
                done: false,
                value: `Value ${this.count}`
            };
        }
    }
}

var test = new MyClass();

declare var console: any;
for (let x of test) {
    console.log(x);
}
```

**Re: `[type]():type` syntax:**

The syntax `[type]():type` you mention is just another way to define members. Also note that `Symbol.iterator` is of type `symbol` and can be used as keys for object properties.

From the [TS documentation](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/symbols.html) page:

> Starting with ECMAScript 2015, symbol is a primitive data type, just
>   like number and string.
>
> Just like strings, symbols can be used as keys
>   for object properties.

So it is similar to doing:

```
interface Test { 
    ["SomeMethod"](): string; 
}    

class TestClass implements Test {
    ["SomeMethod"]() {
        return "hello";
    }
}
```

TS docs on symbols: https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/symbols.html

The below article explains iterators in depth:
https://basarat.gitbooks.io/typescript/content/docs/iterators.html

MDN article on iterators: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Iterators_and_Generators

Comment: thanks, but my question is not about iterator, it's about this particular structure `[Symbol.iterator](): Iterator<string>;`, as in general form `[type]():type`

Comment: That is just another way of defining members. You can do `interface Test { ["SomeMethod"](): string; }`. Similar to how you can do `obj.prop` or `obj["prop"]` in JS.

Comment: _Also note that Symbol.iterator is just a string not some complex type_ - actually `typeof Symbol.iterator` produces `symbol`

Comment: Updated the answer. `symbol` is similar to strings and can be used as object keys.